# Do I need to perform a Purge on my Table

Tags: talend, vertica

I am currently learning about Projections and permanently deleting data from a Vertica table. I understand that when I perform a DELETE on a table it is marked with a delete vector for rolling back purposes.

I am currently learning about Purge Policy and Ancient History Markers which I understand the purpose of and how to do it.

What is was wondering if there is a way to see what data has been marked with a delete vector.  I have seen somewhere there is a delete_Vectors table but i cant seem to locate this anywhere.

**What I am trying to achieve**

I want to set up AHM's or Purge Policy's but I would like to perform soft deletes prior to setting these up so I can simply view the before and after of the purged data.

I have searched the internet and read lots of documentation but I feel some practical work on the world of Purges and Projections will help me understand it more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `v_monitor.delete_vectors`?

Comment: Hmm, not too sure.. That gives me something to go off though.  Thanks very much

Comment: What is the goal of seeing *"before and after of the purged data"*? It will look the same unless you're using epochs

Comment: I see, I think I may have misunderstood.. I am running Talend with Vertica and I have an ETL that inserts rows into a table.  In my Dev environment I have deleted some rows from a table to test my ETL, however the deleted rows are appearing in the results of the ETL but not in the SELECT statement direct to the table.  I am assuming this because of the 'soft delete'. I want to purge to see the data dissapear within my ETL. Does that make sense?

Comment: This could be because there's a commit not being made; not because you're seeing the deleted rows.